# Remove Large Spacing on a Graph Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, graph, charts

I am working on a program and one feature is to show a graph of accrued points by game. I have successfully created the graph but cannot work out how to get rid of the big gaps at either side. I have tried reducing padding and margins to 0 but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Image of graph:
[image]

```vb
Chart1.Series.Clear()
Chart1.Titles.Clear()
Chart1.ChartAreas.Clear()

Chart1.Show()

Chart1.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel()
Chart1.Titles.Add(names(search))
Chart1.ChartAreas.Add("Default")

With Chart1.ChartAreas("Default")
    .AxisX.Interval() = 5
    .AxisY.Interval() = 1
    .AxisY.Title = "Number of Wins"
    .AxisX.Title = "Game"
    .AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(0, 60, "low")
End With

Chart1.SetBounds(270, 200, 510, 250)

Dim ref As Integer = 0

For Each item As DictionaryEntry In gamespoints
    If item.Value > 0 Then
        ref = ref + 1
        Chart1.Series.Add(item.Key)
        If item.Value = max And ref Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Chart1.Series(item.Key).Color = Color.Green
        ElseIf item.Value = max Then
            Chart1.Series(item.Key).Color = Color.LimeGreen
        ElseIf ref Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Chart1.Series(item.Key).Color = Color.Black
        Else
            Chart1.Series(item.Key).Color = Color.DarkGray
        End If
        Chart1.Series(item.Key).Points.AddXY(0, item.Value)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What does this have to do with VBA?

Comment: Sorry it appear that I am mixed up and meant VB.net

Comment: What VB.Net code do you have then?

Comment: it wont let me put it as a comment so I'll add it to the question

Comment: Good! Because code does not belong in comments anyway.

Comment: sorry I'm just new so getting used to how things are done

Comment: Please set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set it as the default for new projects). Then, when you've had a chance to correct the problems Visual Studio will tell you about, please [edit] your question with the latest code: it'll make it much easier for us to help you to get the desired result.

Comment: hey andrew, how does this help? It just seems to have made my program unhappy with data conversions